# Tkinter mainloop() not running - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have designed somewhat of an AI to play 2048. I would like to display the game state after each move the AI makes. To do so, I have created a GUI using Tkinter.
First time using Tkinter, and as the title suggests, it seems like my 'updateDisplay' method blocks the mainloop() from being called. Any help would be appreciated.
The GUI will display if I remove the call to `self.after(1000, self.updateDisplay(ai, game))`. However, it will then obviously not update

```
class GameGrid(Frame):
    def __init__(self,ai, game):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.ai = ai
        self.grid()
        self.master.title('2048')

        #self.gamelogic = gamelogic

        self.grid_cells = []
        self.init_grid()
        self.update_grid_cells()
        self.after(1000, self.updateDisplay(ai, game))
        self.mainloop()


    def updateDisplay(self, ai, game):
        game.move(ai.nextMove(4))
        print "hello"
        for i in range(GRID_LEN):
            for j in range(GRID_LEN):
                new_number = int(game.state[i][j])
                if new_number == 0:
                    self.grid_cells[i][j].configure(text="", bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR_CELL_EMPTY)
                else:
                    self.grid_cells[i][j].configure(text=str(new_number), bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR_DICT[new_number], fg=CELL_COLOR_DICT[new_number])
        if game.over:
            if game.won:
                print 'You Won!'
            else:
                print 'Game Over :( Score:', game.score
            return 0
        else: 
            print "test"
            self.after(10000, self.updateDisplay(ai, game))               



if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    ai = AlphaBetaRecursive(game)
    gui = GameGrid(ai, game)
```

Comment: Perhaps calling [`update_idletasks()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) periodically somewhere in `updateDisplay()` might help. It's unclear where the update function is spending most of its time based on what you've posted so far.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the answer. I didn't post all the code in an attempt to keep it simple. `updateDisplay()`  immediately makes a move, prints `hello` and `test` then calls itself again, seemingly without waiting any period of time at all

Comment: You're aware that you have a 10 second delay coded into the `after()` call within the `updateDisplay` function, right? Also the correct what to call it would be `self.after(1000, self.updateDisplay, self.ai, self.game)` — otherwise you're calling it right in the `after()` call itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `self.after(1000, self.updateDisplay(ai, game))`, you're calling `self.updateDisplay` immediately rather than passing the function as an argument to `after`. You need to get rid of the inner parentheses! According to the docs, `after` does take extra `*args`, but it doesn't actually say what is done with them (maybe they're passed to the callback? I'm not sure). Since `ai` and `game` are already attributes of `self`, you don't actually need to pass them as arguments at all. Just use:

```
self.after(1000, self.updateDisplay)
```

And change the definition of `updateDisplay` to:

```
def updateDisplay(self):
    # use self.ai and self.game rather than ai and game in the implementation of the function
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I have spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure this out. Thanks again

Comment: The extra args are passed to the callback. It's perfeclly safe to do `self.after(1000, self.updateDisplay, ai, game)` though there's no point in passing object attributes around between methods of the same class.